# ROS Subscribe to multiple topics with single function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ros

Thanks for feedback and help in advance,

I want to give input of topic names, initial data and data_type as dictionary to a function, and that function will subscribe to each topic and save data to dictionary. This is what I have done so far.

**Example input**

```
ros_topics = {"rosTopic1": {"data": None,
                            "type": "msg_type1"},
              "rosTopic2": {"data": None,
                            "type": "msg_type2"},
              "rosTopic3": {"data": None,
                            "type": "msg_type3"}}
```

I can subscribe to multiple topics and show their output message, however I couldn't save them into dictionary.

**My function so far**

```
def subscribe_topics(self):
    for key in self.ros_topics.keys():
        rospy.Subscriber(name=key,
                         data_class=self.ros_topics[key]["type"],
                         callback=self.common_callback)

def common_callback(self, msg):
    print("####")
    # Want to store msg.data to ros_topics[key]["data"], however I couldn't transfer **key**
    print(msg)
    print("####")
```

[ROS Answers Question Link](https://answers.ros.org/question/407730/ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics-with-single-function/)

- Python 3.8
- ROS Noetic
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in here: [ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics-with-single-function](https://answers.ros.org/question/407730/ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics-with-single-function/?answer=407733#post-id-407733)